# Was GLaDOS initially "too mean" for Portal 2?

Tags: portal-2

I just read a Youtube comment saying that the developers canned some of GLaDOS dialogue because she was "too mean" for players initially.

Is there actually additional GlaDOS dialogue that didn't make it into into the final cut? Has it been released anywhere, or mentioned in official commentaries?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seems to be asking about the developer's intent and speculation.

Comment: @Schism [I just made a meta post about this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7385/on-questions-of-developer-intent-and-the-routing-around-thereof/7386#7386).  I encourage you to include your viewpoint.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes. The commentary node in one of the first tests says this:

> GLaDOS originally was a lot more cutting in these opening rooms, given that she’s talking to someone she perceives as her murderer. Playtests revealed, though, that it was a bit grueling getting brow-beaten by GLaDOS this early in the game, so her arc was rewritten to give her more of a slow burn towards the player.

I don't think any of the original dialogue from GLaDOS is anywhere in there, though.

Comment: The app-book "The Final Hours of Portal 2" reveals that she was mean and graphical enough in her descriptions of the ways she wanted to kill Chell that even her voice actor started having concerns. Book's available at http://www.thefinalhoursof.com/

Comment: @millenomi Might want to note that that's not a book, but an app for the iPad-only. I would buy it if I had an iPad. :-(

Comment: You can buy it, unzip the application file, and all the pages are just PNGs, so you can read it without an iPad. Not the best experience, but at least the content is accessible.

Comment: @chrismear I can't buy it without an iPad though.

Comment: I don't have an iPad either. I just bought it through iTunes on my Mac.

Comment: Update: the app-book is now on Steam: http://store.steampowered.com/app/104600/

Comment: Still, the book doesn't reveal any actual lines, just mentions about the same as the quote in this answer.