# The Final Hours of Portal 2 without an iPad

Tags: portal-2

I was just wondering if [The Final Hours of Portal 2](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-final-hours-of-portal-2/id432031492?mt=8) is available somehow for people who don't own an iPad?

Thank you!

**EDIT**: It is now possible to get it on Steam : http://store.steampowered.com/app/104600/

Comment: I'm torn, is this really still Game related?

Comment: It's clearly game-related, but loosely gaming-related.  I'd be OK with allowing it.

Comment: This is fine.  There are dozens of questions that are purely lore related and not really "gaming" questions themselves.

Comment: Are you sure?  Because this really feels like [tag:shopping-advice] to me.  Voting to close.

Comment: @GnomeSlice Shopping advice is "should I get this? will I like it? what's my best choice?" Shopping advice wouldn't be off-topic if it could be objectively answered. This has been objectively answered. Ergo, it's not shopping advice. It isn't even asking for *advice*, let alone the shopping variety.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Okay, that makes sense to me.  But I dunno.  Still feels like... I dunno, like someone asking for an emulator for something, you know?  This is all rather irrelevant now given that the game is available for PC, but when it was asked, I don't think it would have been hard to determine it was only available on iOS.  Doesn't really matter at this point, though.

Comment: @GnomeSlice Digging a 2 years old question to close it without a good reason (the fact that it is a "shopping advice" is highly debatable (and totally wrong IMO))... What would that website be without heroes like you?

Comment: @EricGagnon Personally, I voted to close it as too localized, as it's no longer a problem.  Closing questions that are no longer a problem is part of general site cleanup; it's nothing personal against you, and I'll thank you to be polite to Gnome.  All we're trying to do is keep the site clean and organized, and being sarcastic to us just makes a thankless job worse.

Comment: [Can't we all just get along?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPMmC0UAnj0)

Comment: @fbueckert I agree with you, it is definitely "too localized". This question isn't relevant anymore and it won't be of any help to anyone else. However, I still don't see how this question could have been misinterpreted as a shopping advice, which is why I was a bit unhappy about the resolution (I see it as over-moderating). I'm taking this opportunity to thank y'all for the good work. <3

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Straight from The Final Hours of:](http://www.thefinalhoursof.com/)

> **Q: Why would you make this for iPad?  I don’t own an iPad but really want to
>   read it.  It’s not fair!**
>
> A:  I know this will be a frequent
>   question. I started with iPad because
>   I love the device; in many ways it
>   helped inspire me to write this story.
>   It’s a good platform to publish
>   log-form journalism with multimedia
>   elements.  But I do realize that iPads
>   are expensive to own and many Valve
>   fans may not have one.  If the iPad
>   version is somewhat successful I am
>   committed to getting this story onto
>   other platforms. I appreciate your
>   patience.

**But Geoff Keighley changes his mind quickly** so he fixed your problem [by making it available through Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/104600/).

[image]

And just to mess with my answer, they even removed the top part of my answer from the site's FAQ. But I guess we don't care ;-)

Comment: Ping. This is no longer true

Comment: Should we delete it  @Juan?

Comment: I think editing it to reflect the current reality is better. I didn't want to do it myself because it's changing the entire post, and I wanted to let you write it in your style :)

Answer (score 13):

Directly from [Geoff Keighley](http://twitter.com/#!/geoffkeighley) twitter channel, couple of hours ago he said

> To everyone asking, YES, you'll be able to experience Final Hours of Portal 2 on other platforms soon! Thanks for your interest.

So it is just a matter of time now.

**UPDATE:** Portal 2 - Final Hours is now available on [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/104600/) (Mac/PC platforms)

Comment: Specifically: http://twitter.com/#!/geoffkeighley/status/62941843721166848

Answer (score 5):

This was covered in another answer. The app is essentially using .pngs, so if you were desperate, I imagine you could open the app that you've downloaded from iTunes and peruse the PNGs at your leisure.

Check out the comments on the answer here:

[Was GLaDOS Initially Too Mean For Portal 2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20880/was-glados-initially-too-mean-for-portal-2)

> chrismear said: You can buy it, unzip the application file, and all the pages are just PNGs, so you can read it without an iPad. Not the best experience, but at least the content is accessible.

Comment: Actually, it isn't just using .pngs. It's an interactive experience.